# Highlighting areas in leaflet using markers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to highlight an area surrounded by node markers. Currently, I'm doing this by creating polygons. Each node in the database is assigned a polygon ID and those with the same IDs are pushed into the array to act as the vertices of the same polygon.

However, as the data is retrieved from the database in the order they were entered into the table, polygon self-intersection happens like in the picture below:

[Self-intersection in polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dxMY.png)

I've tried to sort the vertices by starting from the first and looking for the nearest node, then from that node I look for the nearest again and so on. It worked for some, but some cases still have self-intersection like this:

[Self-intersection after sorting using nearest node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdQpi.png)

Is there any leaflet plugin that will allow me to highlight an area surrounded by nodes? Below is my code for sorting the vertices. All vertices of the same polygon ID are first pushed into the array "arr" before being sorted.

```
  var i;
  var j;
  var flag = 0;
  var sortedarray = [];
  var finalarray = [];

  for (j = 0; j < initiallength - 1; j++) {
    if (flag == 0) {
      finalarray.push(arr[0]);
      arr.splice(0, 1);
      flag++;
    }

    sortedarray = [];

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var x = L.GeometryUtil.distance(map, finalarray[j], arr[i]);
      sortedarray.push(x);
    }

    var smallest = Math.min.apply(Math, sortedarray);
    var x = sortedarray.indexOf(smallest);
    finalarray.push(arr[x]);

    arr.splice(x, 1);
  }
    var polygon = L.polygon(finalarray).setStyle(myStyle).addTo(map);
```